# Can watchOS be connected to BLE device alone?

Tags: watchkit, core-bluetooth, watchos

I made a bluetooth thermometer for Arduino.
I want to display the temperature by connecting it to my Apple Watch 5.
Can I make an app on my own with the Apple Watch?
it is search my device.
but can't connect.

---

**TransferService.swift**

```
import Foundation
import CoreBluetooth

struct TransferService {
    static let serviceUUID = CBUUID(string: "6e400001-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e")
    static let characteristicUUID = CBUUID(string: "6e400003-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e")
}
```

---

**interfaceController.swift**

```
import WatchKit
import Foundation
import CoreBluetooth

class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {

    @IBOutlet weak var bleLabel: WKInterfaceLabel!
    var centralManager: CBCentralManager!

    var discoveredPeripheral: CBPeripheral?
    var transferCharacteristic: CBCharacteristic?
    var writeIterationsComplete = 0
    var connectionIterationsComplete = 0
    
    let defaultIterations = 5     // change this value based on test usecase
    
    var data = Data()
    
    override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
        print("awake()")
        // Configure interface objects here.
        centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil, options: [CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey: true])
    }
    
    
    private func retrievePeripheral() {
        
        let connectedPeripherals: [CBPeripheral] = (centralManager.retrieveConnectedPeripherals(withServices: [TransferService.serviceUUID]))
        
        print("Found connected Peripherals with transfer service: %@", connectedPeripherals)
        
        if let connectedPeripheral = connectedPeripherals.last {
            print("Connecting to peripheral %@", connectedPeripheral)
            self.discoveredPeripheral = connectedPeripheral
            centralManager.connect(connectedPeripheral, options: nil)
        } else {
            // We were not connected to our counterpart, so start scanning
            centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [TransferService.serviceUUID],
                                               options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey: true])
        }
    }
    
    private func cleanup() {
        // Don't do anything if we're not connected
        guard let discoveredPeripheral = discoveredPeripheral,
            case .connected = discoveredPeripheral.state else { return }
        
        for service in (discoveredPeripheral.services ?? [] as [CBService]) {
            for characteristic in (service.characteristics ?? [] as [CBCharacteristic]) {
                if characteristic.uuid == TransferService.characteristicUUID && characteristic.isNotifying {
                    // It is notifying, so unsubscribe
                    self.discoveredPeripheral?.setNotifyValue(false, for: characteristic)
                }
            }
        }
        
        // If we've gotten this far, we're connected, but we're not subscribed, so we just disconnect
        centralManager.cancelPeripheralConnection(discoveredPeripheral)
    }
    
    private func writeData() {
    
        guard let discoveredPeripheral = discoveredPeripheral,
                let transferCharacteristic = transferCharacteristic
            else { return }
        
        // check to see if number of iterations completed and peripheral can accept more data
        while writeIterationsComplete < defaultIterations && discoveredPeripheral.canSendWriteWithoutResponse {
                    
            let mtu = discoveredPeripheral.maximumWriteValueLength (for: .withoutResponse)
            var rawPacket = [UInt8]()
            
            let bytesToCopy: size_t = min(mtu, data.count)
            data.copyBytes(to: &rawPacket, count: bytesToCopy)
            let packetData = Data(bytes: &rawPacket, count: bytesToCopy)
            
            let stringFromData = String(data: packetData, encoding: .utf8)
            print("Writing %d bytes: %s", bytesToCopy, String(describing: stringFromData))
            
            discoveredPeripheral.writeValue(packetData, for: transferCharacteristic, type: .withoutResponse)
            
            writeIterationsComplete += 1
            
        }
        
        if writeIterationsComplete == defaultIterations {
            // Cancel our subscription to the characteristic
            discoveredPeripheral.setNotifyValue(false, for: transferCharacteristic)
        }
    }
    
    override func willActivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
    }
    
    override func didDeactivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is no longer visible
    }

}

extension InterfaceController: CBCentralManagerDelegate {
    // implementations of the CBCentralManagerDelegate methods

    internal func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {

        switch central.state {
        case .poweredOn:
            // ... so start working with the peripheral
            print("CBManager is powered on")
            retrievePeripheral()
        case .poweredOff:
            print("CBManager is not powered on")
            // In a real app, you'd deal with all the states accordingly
            return
        case .resetting:
            print("CBManager is resetting")
            // In a real app, you'd deal with all the states accordingly
            return
        case .unauthorized:
            // In a real app, you'd deal with all the states accordingly
            if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
                switch central.authorization {
                case .denied:
                    print("You are not authorized to use Bluetooth")
                case .restricted:
                    print("Bluetooth is restricted")
                default:
                    print("Unexpected authorization")
                }
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
            }
            return
        case .unknown:
            print("CBManager state is unknown")
            // In a real app, you'd deal with all the states accordingly
            return
        case .unsupported:
            print("Bluetooth is not supported on this device")
            // In a real app, you'd deal with all the states accordingly
            return
        @unknown default:
            print("A previously unknown central manager state occurred")
            // In a real app, you'd deal with yet unknown cases that might occur in the future
            return
        }
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral,
                        advertisementData: [String: Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        
        // Reject if the signal strength is too low to attempt data transfer.
        // Change the minimum RSSI value depending on your app’s use case.
        guard RSSI.intValue >= -70
            else {
            print("Discovered perhiperal not range : \(peripheral.name), at %d"  , RSSI.intValue)
                return
        }
        
        print("Discovered %s at %d", String(describing: peripheral.name), RSSI.intValue)
        
        // Device is in range - have we already seen it?
        if discoveredPeripheral != peripheral {
            
            // Save a local copy of the peripheral, so CoreBluetooth doesn't get rid of it.
            discoveredPeripheral = peripheral
            
            // And finally, connect to the peripheral.
            print("Connecting to perhiperal %@", peripheral)
            
            centralManager.connect(peripheral, options: nil)
            
        }
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didFailToConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?) {
        print("Failed to connect to %@. %s", peripheral, String(describing: error))
        cleanup()
    }
    
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        print("Peripheral Connected")
        
        // Stop scanning
        centralManager.stopScan()
        print("Scanning stopped")
        
        // set iteration info
        connectionIterationsComplete += 1
        writeIterationsComplete = 0
        
        // Clear the data that we may already have
        data.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
        
        // Make sure we get the discovery callbacks
        peripheral.delegate = self
        
        // Search only for services that match our UUID
        peripheral.discoverServices([TransferService.serviceUUID])
    }
    
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?) {
        print("Perhiperal Disconnected")
        discoveredPeripheral = nil
        
        // We're disconnected, so start scanning again
        if connectionIterationsComplete < defaultIterations {
            retrievePeripheral()
        } else {
            print("Connection iterations completed")
        }
    }

}

extension InterfaceController: CBPeripheralDelegate {
    // implementations of the CBPeripheralDelegate methods

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didModifyServices invalidatedServices: [CBService]) {
        
        for service in invalidatedServices where service.uuid == TransferService.serviceUUID {
            print("Transfer service is invalidated - rediscover services")
            peripheral.discoverServices([TransferService.serviceUUID])
        }
    }

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
        if let error = error {
            print("Error discovering services: %s", error.localizedDescription)
            cleanup()
            return
        }
        
        // Discover the characteristic we want...
        
        // Loop through the newly filled peripheral.services array, just in case there's more than one.
        guard let peripheralServices = peripheral.services else { return }
        for service in peripheralServices {
            peripheral.discoverCharacteristics([TransferService.characteristicUUID], for: service)
        }
    }

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {
        // Deal with errors (if any).
        if let error = error {
            print("Error discovering characteristics: %s", error.localizedDescription)
            cleanup()
            return
        }
        
        // Again, we loop through the array, just in case and check if it's the right one
        guard let serviceCharacteristics = service.characteristics else { return }
        for characteristic in serviceCharacteristics where characteristic.uuid == TransferService.characteristicUUID {
            // If it is, subscribe to it
            transferCharacteristic = characteristic
            peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristic)
        }
        
        // Once this is complete, we just need to wait for the data to come in.
    }
    
    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
        // Deal with errors (if any)
        if let error = error {
            print("Error discovering characteristics: %s", error.localizedDescription)
            cleanup()
            return
        }
        
        guard let characteristicData = characteristic.value,
            let stringFromData = String(data: characteristicData, encoding: .utf8) else { return }
        
        print("Received %d bytes: %s", characteristicData.count, stringFromData)

        if characteristicData.count > 0 {
            DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                self.bleLabel.setText(stringFromData)
            }
            writeData()
        }
    }

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateNotificationStateFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
        if let error = error {
            print("Error changing notification state: %s", error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        
        guard characteristic.uuid == TransferService.characteristicUUID else { return }
        
        if characteristic.isNotifying {
            // Notification has started
            print("Notification began on %@", characteristic)
        } else {
            // Notification has stopped, so disconnect from the peripheral
            print("Notification stopped on %@. Disconnecting", characteristic)
            cleanup()
        }
        
    }

    func peripheralIsReady(toSendWriteWithoutResponse peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        print("Peripheral is ready, send data")
        writeData()
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Have you managed to find a solution for this? I am having the same problem. 
I can discover the device, but the connection never goes through or fails. No delegate method from CBCentralManagerDelegate gets called.